# how to delete row on listView completely

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I have made a context menu for a listview and I have a problem

so when I use delete its doesnt completely delete

at first listview has been deleted but when I go to other activity and back to listView

the item that I delete before still on listview

so this is my code

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private ReminderDB dba;
String title, subject, content;
NoteAdapter noteAdapter;
ArrayList<NoteEntry> notes;
NoteEntry conNote;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dba = new ReminderDB(this);
    dba.open();
    setContentView(R.layout.reminder_main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    noteAdapter = new NoteAdapter(this);
    this.setListAdapter(noteAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(this.getListView());
}


private class NoteAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public NoteAdapter(Context context){
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        notes = new ArrayList<NoteEntry>();
        getData();
    }
    public void getData(){
        Cursor c = dba.getNote();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.TITLE_NAME));
                String subject = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.SUBJECT_NAME));
                String content = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONTENT_NAME));
                NoteEntry temp = new NoteEntry(title,content,subject);
                notes.add(temp);
            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }

    }
    private Holder holder;
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return notes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public NoteEntry getItem(int i) {
        return notes.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if(view == null||view.getTag() == null){
            view = mInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.note_row,null);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.subject = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Note_content);
            holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subject_name);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (Holder) view.getTag();

        }
        holder.mNote = getItem(position);
        holder.title.setText(holder.mNote.getTitle());
        holder.subject.setText(holder.mNote.getSubject());

        view.setTag(holder);
        return view;

    }


    private class Holder {
        NoteEntry mNote;
        public TextView subject;
        public TextView title;
     }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.create_button:
            newActivities();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSetting();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
private void newActivities() {
    Intent newActivities = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewActivities.class);
    startActivity(newActivities);

}

private void openSetting() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    NoteEntry selectNote = (NoteEntry)l.getItemAtPosition(position);
     title = selectNote.getTitle();
     subject = selectNote.getSubject();
     content = selectNote.getContent();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShowNote.class);
    intent.putExtra("subject",subject);
    intent.putExtra("title",title);
    intent.putExtra("content",content);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu,menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.view:
            viewNote(info.position);
            return true;
        case R.id.edit:
            editNote(info.position);
            return true;
        case R.id.delete:
            deleteNote(info.position);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void viewNote(int position) {
    NoteEntry selectNote = (NoteEntry) this.getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
    title = selectNote.getTitle();
    subject = selectNote.getSubject();
    content = selectNote.getContent();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShowNote.class);
    intent.putExtra("subject",subject);
    intent.putExtra("title",title);
    intent.putExtra("content",content);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void deleteNote(int position) {
    dba.open();
    dba.deleteNote(position);
    dba.close();
    this.notes.remove(position);
    noteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

 private void editNote(int position) {
   }
 }
```

NewActivities.java

```
public class NewActivities extends Activity {
EditText subET, titleET, contentET;
TextView tutorial;
Button submit;
ReminderDB dba;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_activities);
    dba = new ReminderDB(this);
    dba.open();
    tutorial = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tutorial);
    subET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_subject);
    titleET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_note);
    contentET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_content);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                try{
                    saveToDB();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    });


}
public void saveToDB(){
    dba.insertNotes(titleET.getText().toString(), contentET.getText().toString()
            , subET.getText().toString());
    dba.close();
    titleET.setText("");
    contentET.setText("");
    subET.setText("");
    Intent i = new Intent(NewActivities.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Create Successfull",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
 }
```

ReminderDB.java

```
public class ReminderDB {
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private final Context context;
private final NoteDBHelper dbhelper;
private String[] allcolumns = {Constants.SUBJECT_NAME,Constants.TITLE_NAME,Constants.CONTENT_NAME};

public ReminderDB(Context c){
    context = c;
    dbhelper = new NoteDBHelper(context);
    db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
public void close(){
    db.close();
}
public void open() throws SQLiteException {
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
public long insertNotes(String title,String content,String S_name){
        ContentValues newTaskValue = new ContentValues();
        newTaskValue.put(Constants.TITLE_NAME, title);
        newTaskValue.put(Constants.CONTENT_NAME, content);
        newTaskValue.put(Constants.SUBJECT_NAME, S_name);

        return db.insert(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null,newTaskValue );
}
public Cursor getNote(){

    Cursor cursor =  db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME,allcolumns,null,null,null,null,null);

    return cursor;
}
public void deleteNote(int position){
    db.delete(Constants.TABLE_NAME,Constants.NOTE_ID+" = "+position,null);
  }
}
```

thx for your help :))

Comment: I don't think you actually deleted that record from your database. That's why the row appears when you return back to the list activity. Add your ReminderDB class too, if you think otherwise.

Comment: Yup @Jan i think record is not deleted from database .

Comment: I already edit to add ReminderDB class pls try to look for help thx

Answer (score 0):

Just try for this code,

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
 {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // delete query fire here whatever related to requirements.
        mList.remove(position);//you can delete your item here
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

This method used for **notifyDataSetChanged()** refresh to getView() method from your BaseAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You cannot guarantee that the position on the list is the same as your id. Your id most probably is an auto increment index. (I cannot see db create statements here..) Which means when you delete a row your application will simply delete a wrong row..

Pass this function the id of the record coming from your database. I use view tags in order to store those id's.

```
public void deleteNote(int id) {
  String[] whereArgs = new String[1];
  whereArgs[0] = String.valueOf(id);

  int deletedRowCount = db.delete(Constants.TABLE_NAME, Constants.NOTE_ID + " == ?", whereArgs);

  if (deletedRowCount > 0) {
    Log.d("DB", deletedRowCount + " record(s) deleted.");
  }
}
```